# Unable to detect Beacon device when iPhone sleeps.(goes background)

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon

I am trying to detect iBeacon devices from Application on iPhone.

It detects iBeacon device while running, but when I lock an iPhone, 
it cannot detect (lose) the same iBeacon device.
(Proximity:Unknown RSSI:0 Accuracy:-1.0)
It can detect other device as Android (App:Locate Beacon) on the same condition.

Can anyone help me to find the reason and solution?

Note:

iPhone <=> iBeacon device Fail
iPhone <=> Android (App:Locate Beacon/iBeacon) Ok

Android:AltBeacon does good for same device.

Android <=> iBeacon device Ok

Answer (score 0):

iOS Apps must dynamically request and obtain permission from the user to "Always" access location data in order to detect beacons in the background.  As of iOS 13 the flow has changed, and the operating system makes it harder to obtain the "Always" permission from the user.

Read more here: http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2019/10/18/permission-denied

To verify if your app has obtained the required permission, go to Settings-> App Name -> Location and see if it has "Always" permission to access location data.

Comment: Thank you for all your assistance.  But the setting is "Always".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an iOS device as an iBeacon transmitter, the transmission will no longer work if the app is not visible on the screen.  iPhone apps are not able to emit beacon advertisements when not in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem.
A similar post in the Apple Developer Forums in the past has not been resolved.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115996

Comment: Thank you for all your assistance.